# How to set argv[0] name for ps when spawning program from Java's getRuntime().exec()?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

How to set argv[0] name for ps when spawning program from java getRuntime().exec()?

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "ls > hello"};
rt.exec(cmd);
```

I want the process to have another name in ps ef output.
In C you can just overwrite argv[0] pointer, how to do it in java?

Answer (score 0):

In Java you would need to create a symbolic link to the executable and call that instead. I don't believe you have access to the `argv[0]`

Answer (score -2):

@user1335897: ProcessBuilder provides more flexibility than Runtime, try using following code:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);

    if (envMap != null) {
        processBuilder.environment().putAll(envMap);
    }

    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
}
```